# same page route using anchor tag in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, swagger-ui

I have implemented swagger-ui(swagger-ui.js) in my angular2 application. When it is rendered and I click on any link(#!users/get_user) it routes to the link instead of scrolling to that div.

```
window['swaggerUi'] = new window['SwaggerUi']({
                spec: this.swaggerJson,
                dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
                supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'],
                useJQuery: true,
                onComplete: function () {
                    }
                    window['jQuery']('pre code').each(function (i, e) {
                        window['hljs'].highlightBlock(e)
                    });
                },
                onFailure: function (data) {
                    console.log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
                },
                docExpansion: "none",
                sorter: "alpha"
            });
```

The links which contain href are routing but the link which contain data-id are working fine.
How can i block the routing of those link.

```
 <a href="#!/users/get_users_userid" class="toggleOperation">Users</a> 
 <!-- routes to that url(localhost:8080/#!/users/get_users_userid) -->

 <a href="#" class="expandResource" data-id="users">Expand Operations</a> 
 <!-- it expands the div -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I changed in swagger-ui.js.

I changed the href to href="" for the elements which were causing the routing when clicked.

This is a workaround, but it works for now. :)